# How session variable accessed from adminhtml/session?

Tags: magento-1.9, session, admin-panel

I set Session variable for my array and I want to use on another page, but Nothing found in return.
Like: 
(In My custom Module's Controller file)
Here `$datas` is My array.

```
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setDatas($datas);
```

And Use :

```
$my_data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getDatas();

echo"<pre>";print_r($my_data);
```

But not get anything.
Please suggest what can I do.

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know

Answer (score 0):

I dont know this will work or not but you can try like this

```
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setData($datas);
$my_data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getData();
print_r($my_data);
```

Use `setData()` and `getData()` instead of `Datas`

Please try and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Please use admin/session instead of adminhtml/session

```
$datas = 'Hello world';

Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->setDatas($datas);

$my_data = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getDatas();

echo"<pre>";print_r($my_data);
```